# How can I get msmtp to send system messages to my email?

Tags: debian, email, email-server, system-monitoring, msmtp

I used to use ssmtp on Debian Stretch. Whenever there are system emails, they would get sent to my admin email. It was quite good because I would get a report on all my servers. This was true until in Debian Buster ssmtp was discontinued in the package manager. So I removed it for security reasons.

What I did in ssmtp, besides configuring the authentication, was just editing the file `/root/.forward` and writing there the email address where I'd like to receive my messages. And everything would work just fine.

But now, with msmtp, I don't get that anymore. I don't know how to make it do the same.

Now the configuration of msmtp is correct. I can verify this by running:

```
echo "hello there username." | msmtp -a default myemail@example.com
```

And that works just fine and sends me an email.

How can I get msmtp to send me system emails to some target address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you have to define the an aliases file. Instructions can be found [here](https://websistent.com/msmtp-cron/).